# reading and displaying strings from file

Tags: c++, file, stream, operator-overloading

I stored some strings in a text file using overloaded insertion operator.

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & obj,Person & p)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << strlen(p.last) << p.last << strlen(p.first) << p.first
       << strlen(p.city) << p.city << strlen(p.state) << p.state;
    obj << ss.str();return obj;
}
```

The contents of file look like this

```
4bill5gates7seattle10washington
```

I now need to read the length first and display the string.And continue to display all the strings.How to do this with an overloaded extraction operator?

Comment: Will the strings ever have numbers in them?

Comment: You should have put spaces in between the outputs to make it easier to read.

Comment: The file format is not well defined. Eg: 4shopt424/7 (a 24/7 shop)

Comment: @NathanOliver I was supposed to do it that way.
Only the length followed by string.While reading,i am supposed to read the length first and display a string of that length.

Comment: @DieterLücking I agree.But i am supposed to do it that way.

Comment: @NathanOliver: And to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: Fortunately, names of people and cities do not tend to start with numbers! And the fact that you already know the problem if they do, means you have succeeded at that part of the learning exercise. So I don't see a big problem here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit t is a typo - 4 the size of 24/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it one character at a time and use `std::string::push_back` to append to a string variable.  There's a `std::stoi` which will convert your string lengths to an integer.  Might I suggest that when you create your text file that you put a whitespace after your integer length, then you can just `cin >> string_length` and avoid using `if` statements to control when you've found the end of a number, or the beginning of a new string.

Also, it would be more beneficial, if you showed us what you've attempted, so that we could help you more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::istringstream in("4bill5gates7seattle10washington");
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    unsigned length;
    while(in >> length) {
        std::string s;
        if(in >> std::setw(length) >> s)
            strings.push_back(s);
    }
    for(const auto& s : strings)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

**Disclaimer:** The file format is evil.

Note: This does not extract a 'Person', but fields. I leave that to you.

Answer (score -1):

Make `operator <<` like this

```
ostream & operator >> ( ostream & obj, Person & p )
{

    obj << strlen( p.last ) << " " << p.last << " " << strlen( p.first ) << " " << p.first << " "
        << strlen( p.city ) << " " << p.city << " " << strlen( p.state ) << " " << p.state;

    return obj;
}
```

and `operator >>` like this

```
istream & operator >> ( istream & obj, Person & p )
{
    obj >> p.last >> p.first >> p.city >> p.state;

    return obj;
}
```